# Whitespace is getting added after custom header and before footer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, html-to-pdf

**My code is as below:**

```
    const browser = await this.Puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(`<html>
                            <body style="background-color: #434244; color: #fff">
                                <div>Page body</div>
                            </body>
                          </html>`);    
    const headerFooterCss = `<style>#header, #footer { padding:0;}</style>`;
    const options = {
      displayHeaderFooter: true,
      printBackground: true,
      preferCSSPageSize: false,
      headerTemplate: `
                   ${headerFooterCss}
                   <div style='width: 100%; height: 100%;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; background-color: #434244'>
                       <div style='text-align: center; height: 100%;color: #fff;background: #434244; font-size: 14px'> Header content</div>
                   </div>`,
      footerTemplate: `
                      ${headerFooterCss}
                     <div style='width: 100%; height: 100%;margin-bottom: 0;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; background-color: #434244''>
                         <div style='text-align: center; color: #fff;background: #434244; font-size: 14px'> Footer content</div>
                     </div>`,
      margin: {
        top: "30px",
        bottom: "30px",
      },
    };

    const buffer = await page.pdf(options);
```

**Output pdf:**

[image: pdf]

It is adding some whitespace (notice small line in image) after header and before footer. I don't know which config I am missing/wrong.

Please help me to figure it out.

**Note:** When I download the pdf and open in in chrome, it is not getting noticed. But If I open file in pdf viewer app like Previw in mac, I can see that whitespace

Thanks

Comment: Look into sub-pixel rounding. Rather than background on each section, maybe put background on the outer element.

Comment: @isherwood already tried that, but not worked. I see same behaviour with phantomjs as well.

Comment: You tried what? I gave you two possible solutions. You might make your height `calc(100% + .1px)` to deal with the rounding issue.

Comment: I've tried to apply background on only outer element, and also tried calc(100% + .1px). none of worked. Apart from that, I don't know much about sub-pixel rounding, sorry for that :(

Comment: Which is why I suggested looking into it. That means researching and understanding. Thin lines like that often have rounding as a cause.

Comment: Yes, I am looking into it.